# whats wrong with this code?

Tags: java

for some reason everything i input anything i keep on getting empty lines
i am trying to make a program that reads the input , removes all unnecessary white spaces but one space between each word. then print out all the lines.

not using any sentinels to stop .

```
import java.util.Scanner ;
import java.lang.Character;
import java.lang.String ;
public class trim
{
        public static void main (String[]args)
        {

          String SongName = " " ;
          String Song = " " ;
          int i = 0 ;
          int count = 0 ;

                 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                while(scan.hasNextLine())
                {
                  count++;
                  scan.nextLine();
                }


                 for (  ; i < count ; i ++)
                 {
                   if (scan.hasNext())
                   {
                    SongName =scan.nextLine() ;
                    SongName = SongName.trim() ;
                    SongName = SongName.replaceAll("\\s+"," ");
                    if (Song== " " )
                    {
                    Song = SongName;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    Song  = Song + "\n" +SongName ;
                    }
                   }
                   System.out.println(Song) ;

                }

         }
}
```

Comment: `if (Song== " " )` is probably not your problem here, but please use `equals` anyway.

Comment: refer [this](http://v4all123.blogspot.com/2012/12/string.html) post. I think you will get it.

Answer (score 5):

```
while(scan.hasNextLine()){
       count++;
       scan.nextLine();
}
```

This will read all input before your program even really starts.

After that (if the program even gets that far, STDIN usually does not ever close on a console), scan has nothing more to read in the second loop.

Also, lower-case class names are as confusing as upper-case variable names. At least you are consistent here ;-)

Comment: thanks ill try to figure out how to get it to count the lines to set a limit then go back and reread the input. im thinking i should make the count the lines a program by itself and just run that program. then have my main program read the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    count++;
    scan.nextLine();
}
```

This seems to be an infinite loop to me. It just keeps reading input from the console. You keep typing and this keeps reading.

Comment: Not necessarily infinite. Close the stream and it will terminate. But then the second loop has nothing more to read.

Comment: How will you close the stream, when the control never goes out of it.

Comment: It'll basically never stop reading, unless you kill the program.

Comment: May be I'm missing something, because am using eclipse? Nevertheless, that loop is quite troublesome.

Comment: Yes, it is. A regular console never closes the stream. If you piped in a file, you would see the loop terminating. But then there is no more to read for that second loop.

Answer (score 0):

Add your inputs to a list and then you can proceed the logic. I have modified the code as below.

```
import java.util.Scanner ;
import java.util.ArrayList ;
import java.lang.Character;
import java.lang.String ;

public class trim {

public static void main (String[]args) {
    String SongName = " " ;
    String Song = " " ;          
    int count = 0 ;
ArrayList lst = new ArrayList();

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(scan.hasNextLine()) {                  
        lst.add(scan.nextLine());
        count++;
    }

for (int i=0 ; i < count ; i ++)  {                   
    SongName = (String)lst.get(i);  
    SongName = SongName.trim() ;
    SongName = SongName.replaceAll("\\s+"," ");
    if (Song== " " ) {
       Song = SongName;
    }
    else  {
       Song  = Song + "\n" +SongName ;
    }                   
    }
System.out.println(Song) ;
  }
}
```

Comment: when i compile that code i get this

Note: trim.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.